# how can filter json code

Tags: php, json

i have json file like below:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "id": 8921,
        "weather": null,
        "status": "TT",
    }, {"id": 8922,
        "weather": null,
        "status": "TF",
    },
    {
        "id": 8923,
        "weather": null,
        "status": "NT",
    }, {"id": 8922,
        "weather": null,
        "status": "HT",
    }

    ]
}
```

i read this and show in table
but i want filter that with status and get just status have TF and size depend on.

old code without check status:

```
$jsonResult = file_get_contents('1.json');
$content_json = json_decode($jsonResult);
$size=sizeof($content_json->data);
```

the new code (did'nt work true):

```
$jsonResult = $jsonResult = file_get_contents('1.json');
$content_json = json_decode($jsonResult);
$content_json = array_filter($content_json['data'], function ($data) {
    return $data['status'] != 'HT' or  $data['status'] != 'NT';

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the data array to check the status:

```
$jsonResult = file_get_contents('1.json');
$content_json = json_decode($jsonResult, true);
$data = $content_json['data'];
$filteredData = [];
foreach($data as $entry){
    if($entry['status'] == "TF")
        $filteredData[] = $entry;
}

$size = sizeof($filteredData);
```

Also, your `JSON` file has a syntax error, remove the commas after the status properties like so:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "id": 8921,
        "weather": null,
        "status": "TT"
    }, {"id": 8922,
        "weather": null,
        "status": "TF"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays as opposed to objects (pass true as the second parameter to `json_decode()`), you can use `array_filter()` to remove any elements your not interested in...

```
$content_json = json_decode($jsonResult,true);
$content_json = array_filter($content_json['data'], function ($data) {
    return $data['status'] == 'TF';
});

echo count($content_json);
```

Update:

Your code should be...

```
$content_json = json_decode($jsonResult, true);
$content_json = array_filter($content_json['data'], function ($data) {
    return $data['status'] != 'HT' and  $data['status'] != 'NT';

});
```

Note the `,true` on the `json_decode()` and the condition should be `and` not `or`.

Comment: this code not work for multi check. i want return $data['status'] != 'cn' or  $data['status'] != 'tf'; or return $data['status'] == 'df' or  $data['status'] == 'dd';

Comment: If you want it be not cn and not tf you need to use `$data['status'] != 'cn' and $data['status'] != 'tf`` So it's AND in the middle

Comment: Also if you want it match upper or lower case, then add `strtolower()` to `$data['status']` and check it all against lower case.

Comment: no i write exactly alphabetic in json "FT" but not work. this return all data

Comment: I know you shouldn't do this, but can you add the code and data to the question and I will check it.

Comment: As you seem to have found an answer, I will leave it there